# How do I enter document ID/template ID into a Google Script in order to autofill a template?

Tags: google-apps-script

Looking to build a Google Script that will insert entries into a document based on certain entries, either from prompts or text fields (ex. what's typed as Name replaces each instance of ##name## in the text below.) The closest I've found to what I need is this blog https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/google-docs-scripts-automate/. However, when I go to enter the document ID as instructed, the code results in an error. My code so far is below. I've been replacing each instance of (documentID) with the part after document/d in a Google Doc (10IUD6NDli_DThIO4nGaoTYvtcMgIggcB2Gl5zYN8F3Q) to no avail. I am getting the prompts and able to answer them, but no copy is being saved to my Drive's root folder.

```
function myFunction() {
  // Display a dialog box for each field you need information for.
  
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  //var response = ui.prompt('Enter Name', 'Enter sales person's name', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  var nameResponse = ui.prompt('Enter sales persons name');
  var client1Response = ui.prompt('Enter client 1');
  var sales1Response = ui.prompt('Enter sales 1');
    
  //Make a copy of the template file
  var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById('<my-template-id>').makeCopy().getId();
      
  //Rename the copied file
  DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName(nameResponse.getResponseText() + date + ' Sales Report');  
      
  //Get the document body as a variable
  var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();
    
  //Insert the entries into the document
  body.replaceText('##name##', nameResponse.getResponseText());
  body.replaceText('##client1##', client1Response.getResponseText());
  body.replaceText('##sales1##', sales1Response.getResponseText());
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Are you hard coding this `<my-template-id>`?

Answer (score 0):

To use this, you will need to bind the script to your template document by opening the document and navigating to [Tools > Script editor]. Paste and save the code below, then reopen the document. Use [Report > Create report] to enter your desired info and create a new report. Use [Report > Reset template] to restore the markup for the next usage.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  let ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Report')
    .addItem('Create report', 'createReport')
    .addItem('Reset template', 'resetTemplate')
    .addToUi();
}

/**
 * Creates a copy of the active document, replacing markup with user-specified values.
 */
const createReport = function() {
  try {
    Drive.Files.list();
  }
  catch (e) {
    throw new Error(`Add the 'Drive' service (Services > Drive > Add) to use this function.`);
  }
  
  // Script is container-bound, no ID needed
  let document  = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  let ui        = DocumentApp.getUi();
  
  // Get desired information from user
  let name    = handlePrompt('Enter Name', 'Please enter name of salesperson:', UI);
  let client1 = handlePrompt('Enter Client 1', 'Please enter client 1:', UI);
  let sales1  = handlePrompt('Enter Sales 1', 'Please enter sales 1:', UI);
  if ((name || client1 || sales1) === null)
    return;
  
  // Get the document body
  let body = document.getBody();
  
  // Replace markup with values
  body.replaceText('##name##', name);
  body.replaceText('##client1##', client1);
  body.replaceText('##sales1##', sales1);
  
  // Store values in script properties for the reset() function
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
    .setProperties({
      name:     name,
      client1:  client1,
      sales1:   sales1
    });
  
  // Save copy to Drive
  let resource = {
    title: document.getName()
  };
  Drive.Files.copy(resource, document.getId());
  
  return;
}

/**
 * Resets the document by restoring markup code.
 */
const resetTemplate = function() {
  // Get properties from store
  let properties  = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  let name        = properties.getProperty('name');
  let client1     = properties.getProperty('client1');
  let sales1      = properties.getProperty('sales1');
  
  // Replace values with markup
  let document  = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  let body      = document.getBody();
  body.replaceText(name, '##name##');
  body.replaceText(client1, '##client1##');
  body.replaceText(sales1, '##sales1##');
  
  return;
}

const handlePrompt = function(title, message, ui) {
  let prompt = ui.prompt(title, message, ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  return prompt.getSelectedButton() === ui.Button.OK ?
    prompt.getResponseText() : null;
}
```